# Fetch the the path of a file at changeset without using the workspace

Tags: java, rtc, jazz, ibm-jazz

I am searching for a .txt file that is located at change set.
Then I need to create locally over my pc  the full path directory of this file.

For example if there a file called"test.txt" that it's located at:
Project1-->Folder1-->Folder2-->test.txt

Till now I have managed to search for this file.
Now I need to fetch the full directory and create similar one over my pc:
Result at my pc:
Folder1-->Folder2-->test.txt

That's what I did to search for the file  within a changeset and retrieve it:

```
public IFileItem getTextFileFile(IChangeSet changeSet, ITeamRepository repository) throws TeamRepositoryException{
    IVersionableManager vm = SCMPlatform.getWorkspaceManager(repository).versionableManager();
    List changes = changeSet.changes();
    IFileItem toReturn = null;
    for(int i=0;i<changes.size();i++) {="" <br="">             Change change = (Change) changes.get(i);
        IVersionableHandle after = change.afterState();
        if( after != null && after instanceof IFileItemHandle) {
            IFileItem fileItem = (IFileItem) vm.fetchCompleteState(after, null);
            if(fileItem.getName().contains(".txt")) {
                   toReturn = fileItem;
                   break;
            } else {
               continue;
            }
        }
    }
    if(toReturn == null){
        throw new TeamRepositoryException("Could not find the file");
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

I have searched & posted at the forums and most of things I found is that I can use:
configuration.determineAncestorsInHistory

However in order to get the IConfiguration,I need for workspaceConnection which is not valid at my case.

Thanks.

I use RTC:4
Win:XP

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Files/Folders have an identity that is independent of their name/path.  This allows tracking the file across renames/moves.  The name/path of the file can be different depending on the history of changes made to that file (or to the containing folders).

This means that if you don't have a workspace (or a baseline) which points to the specific point in history that you care about, then you can't be sure what the path actually is.  The `IConfiguration.determineAncestorsInHistory` is really the only way to get the path.

There is an algorithm buried deep in the server that makes a guess at a "popular" path for the file but this is not exposed anywhere.